# Smart Card - Update Record command return 6D 00

Tags: java, smartcard, javacard

I'm writing a smart card program for ISO 7816 Cards which I need to update a record. I write the program with JAVA and `javax.smartcardio` Library.

I select the file with this command: `ins = 0xA4`

I can read record with this command: `cla = 0x80` , `ins = 0xB2` , `p1 = 0x00` , `p2 = 0x00` , `le = 90`

Read record works correct and send me `90 00`.
Now I need to update this record. So I use this command: `cla = 0x80` , `ins = 0xDC` , `p1 = 0x00` , `p2 = 0x00` , and some data.

But in response APDU I get `6D 00` Error which means "Ins Value not supported".

How can I update records correctly?

Comment: What card is this? Why do you expect the record to be writable (with this command / without authentication / at all)?

Comment: @MichaelRoland It's ISO 7816-4 smart card... I have the source code of the program which use for reading the datas of card... I thought that I can change command to change data of this file... but it's not authentication problem because error is about ins value... It's not possible?

Comment: ISO/IEC 7816-4 is a standard defining the data structures and a set of commands for smartcards, it's not a smartcard *product*. Smartcards may follow *parts* of ISO/IEC 7816-4 but typically don't implement all commands. Specifically the command that your card supports (CLA=`80`, INS=`B2`) is a proprietary command that does not follow the ISO/IEC 7816-4 standard (CLA=`80` indicates the proprietary class). You would need to get more information about the smartcard chip (and possibly the applications running on it) in order to determine if (and how) data structures on the chip could be modified.

Comment: @MichaelRoland Thank You Micheal... I Don't know so much about smart card programming and I Thought there is same instruction for all smart card... So I should contact with company and take some information about this smart card instructions...

Comment: You can analyse the ATR and guess the smart card type.

Comment: For a quick check you could try *Write Record (INS=0xD2)* instead of *Update Record (INS=0xDC)*

Answer (score -2):

I have this command: `00 DC 01 04`. It works:

```
00 : class     
DC : INS  
01 : P1 , position of record  
04 : P2 ,
```

Cordially.